# how to Draw points or line in the spaces before text in every line - in Java

Tags: java, android

I need some help to make this idea work, what I want is to draw pints or line before every space in every line in edittext onDraw method.
for example i want the text or code or any content to have look like this :

```
_____for (int i=0; i< count; i++) {
___________some code here
____________}
```

or look like this :

```
.........for (int i=0; i< count; i++) {
............some code here
..............}
```

I tested and tried to do it, and it works but I have a small problem, that is
when the cursor position or text is in the center of line, I get no line drawing or the line is to short then the space between start of line and the start of text.

picture of my problem :

[![enter image description here][1]][1]
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ly5du.png

the Code I'm using is :

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class customEditText extends androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatEditText {
    private Paint mPaint = new Paint();
    private int position;

    public customEditText(Context context) {
        super(context);
        initPaint();
    }

    public customEditText(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        initPaint();
    }

    public customEditText(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
        initPaint();
    }

    private void initPaint() {
        mPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
        mPaint.setColor(0x80000000);
    }
    @Override
    protected void onSelectionChanged(int selStart, int selEnd) {
        position = selStart;
    }

    @Override protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {

        int left = getLeft();
        int paddingLeft = getPaddingLeft();

        for (int i = 0; i < getLineCount(); i++) {


            int ii = i;

            try {
                Matcher m = Pattern.compile("^\\s+|\n\\s+").matcher(getText().toString().split("\n")[ii]);
                if (m.find()) {
                    int baseline = getLayout().getLineBaseline(ii);

                    float x = getLayout().getPrimaryHorizontal(m.end());

                    canvas.drawLine(left + paddingLeft, baseline, x, baseline, mPaint);
                }
            } catch (Exception r){
                r.printStackTrace();
            }

            }

        super.onDraw(canvas);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The method [getPrimaryHorizontal()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/Layout#getPrimaryHorizontal(int)) gives you

> the location where a new character would be inserted in the paragraph's primary direction

This means you'll get a pixel value, to be measured from the `View`'s left border.

If you type just one space, `x` may be smaller than `left + paddingLeft`. So the line will in fact be drawn from *startY* to *startX*. If you add more spaces, the difference between `x` and  `left + paddingLeft` will change, causing the line first to vanish and then to reappear, but now really drawn from *startX* to *startY*.

Since `getLeft()` only gives you the distance of the `View`'s left border to its parent `ViewGroup`'s left border, you don't need to add the value of to the starting point of the line.

But you may want to keep `getPaddingLeft()`. If you do, you should add it to both the *startX* value and the *startY* value:

```
 canvas.drawLine(paddingLeft, baseline, paddingLeft + x, baseline, mPaint);
```

Comment: thanks so much, I understand now what was my mistake